# WP e-commerce plugin add custom checkout field

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add custom field on checkout page programmatically.

Any idea how I can do it (WP e-commerce plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears WP e-Commerce handles this out of the box:

http://docs.wpecommerce.org/checkout/

Scroll to the very bottom -- It mentions being able to add your own unique fields on checkout, from a tab in the admin settings.

Comment: Yeah I guess it will be a best way to do it... Thanks Greg!